# Searching text file and showing part of the text in a text box

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a VB.net application where I have a very large text file. It is basically a large database of error codes with descriptions of how to clear the code after it. What I would like to do, is on the click of a button, search the text file for the specific code and display all text for just that error code into a text box. I have tried many different ways, but am unable to get it to work properly. I went through the entire text file and added a `"|"` to the beginning of each fault code so that I could specify where the code starts at.

Here is an example of a couple fault codes:

> |ACAL-000 Fail to run DETECT Motn Cause: The AccuCal2 Motion failed to
>   nm.  The AccuCal2 motion cannot be started.  Remedy: Clear all the
>   errors before executing AccuCal2. |ACAL-001  Robot is  not ready.
>   Cause:  The robot is not ready.  The system cannot issue motion
>   because it is in an error state.  Remedy: Clear all faults, then retry
>   the operation.

If I search for `"ACAL-000"`, I want it to show everything from the `|` before `ACAL-000` to the bar before `ACAL-001`.

I would post the code that I have written, but I have tried so many different versions that I don't really know which one to post.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is my current code after some editing and implementation of what has been recommended. Please see the comments below for more information on how I got to this point. A quick note, I am currently just using "|ACAL-000" for a test search. When this is complete, I have some other (already working) code that will put together a code from a couple of drop down lists.

```
Function ReadEmbeddedTextFileResource(embeddedResourceName As String) As String

    Using stream As Stream = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedResourceName)

        If stream Is Nothing Then
            Throw New FileNotFoundException("The resource '" & embeddedResourceName & "' was not found.")
        End If

        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream, True)
            Return reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using

    End Using

End Function

Function FindTextBetweenBars(bodyOfTextToSearch As String, textToLookFor As String) As String

    Dim i As Integer = bodyOfTextToSearch.IndexOf(textToLookFor)
    If i < 0 Then Return Nothing

    Dim j As Integer = bodyOfTextToSearch.LastIndexOf("|", i)
    If j < 0 Then j = 0

    Dim k As Integer = bodyOfTextToSearch.IndexOf("|", i + Len(textToLookFor))
    If k < 0 Then k = Len(bodyOfTextToSearch)

    Return bodyOfTextToSearch.Substring(j + 1, k - j - 1)

End Function

Private Sub btnShowTroubleshooting_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowTroubleshooting.Click
    Dim allErrorText As String = ReadEmbeddedTextFileResource(My.Resources.FanucCodes)
    Dim errorMessage As String = FindTextBetweenBars(allErrorText, "|ACAL-000")
    If errorMessage Is Nothing Then errorMessage = "Error code Not found!"
    RichTextBoxFanucFaults.Text = errorMessage

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that should do what you want:

```
Function FindTextBetweenBars(bodyOfTextToSearch As String, textToLookFor As String) As String

    Dim i As Integer = bodyOfTextToSearch.IndexOf(textToLookFor)
    If i < 0 Then Return Nothing

    Dim j As Integer = bodyOfTextToSearch.LastIndexOf("|", i)
    Dim k As Integer = bodyOfTextToSearch.IndexOf("|", i + Len(textToLookFor))
    If k < 0 Then k = Len(bodyOfTextToSearch)

    Return bodyOfTextToSearch.Substring(j + 1, k - j - 1)

End Function
```

In your button click event handler you can call the function like this:

```
Dim errorMessage as String = FindTextBetweenBars(My.Resources.FanucCodes, txtErrorCodeToLookFor.Text)
If errorMessage Is Nothing Then errorMessage = "Error code not found!"
txtErrorMessage.Text = errorMessage
```

where `txtErrorMessage` is the output textbox to display the error message result,
`My.Resources.FanucCodes` is your large string resource containing all the error descriptions (with `|` separators), and `txtErrorCodeToLookFor` is a textbox that accepts the error code input from the user.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I entered in all of the code and it definitely got me much closer, but it displays "Error code not found!" every time. I think this is because I am not opening the text file that I am searching properly. I added the text file in as an embedded resource and made sure that my project was pointing to the correct file. I added in my file name "filename.txt" in place of allErrorText, hoping that it would open it up and search it, since it is part of the project, but that did not work. How would I open the text file and get it to search within it?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  The code above assumes you have already read the text from the file into a string variable.  I'll edit in a few minutes to show how to read from a file.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help Brian!

Comment: Here is the error that I am currently getting:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in RWC3Control.exe"

It says it can't find it, but then it says all of this in the error, which makes me think it is finding it, but the search isn't working correctly?

"Additional information: The resource '|ACAL-000 Fail to run DETECT Motn

Cause: The AccuCal2 Motion failed to nm.  The AccuCal2 motion cannot be started.........................And on and on....................."

Comment: I added my current code into the description under the "EDIT" header. I am hoping this might clear it up a bit.

Comment: It sounds to me like `My.Resources.FanucCodes` is actually the *contents* of the error file, not the name of a resource.  If that is the case, then that means that you already have the text to search, so you don't need the `ReadEmbeddedTextFileResource` function at all.  Instead, plug the contents into the `FindTextBetweenBars` function like I originally suggested.  `Dim errorMessage as String = FindTextBetweenBars(My.Resources.FanucCodes, txtErrorCodeToLookFor.Text)`

Comment: This fixed it for me Brian. Thank you. I had been beating my head against the wall for a while on this one. You have been a huge help!

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad you were able to get it working.